# I can't install PDO on centos

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't install PDO on centos. I'm useing APM, but want to use PDO.

I did `yum install php-pdo` and I can find `pdo_mysql.so`, added it to `php.ini` (deleted ";" before "extension=pdo_mysql.dll"):

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension_dir=/usr/lib64/php/modules
```

This root is "pdo_mysql.so" root. But it does not work. In phpinfo I see no `pdo_mysql_driver`

I can't update to php version. This server is not mine. How can I use PDO?

I use Centos6 and PHP5.2

Comment: (Warning: I don't have a local install of CentOS.) I don't think you'll see "pdo_mysql_driver" through phpinfo(). I think you should see `PDO drivers => mysql, pgsql, sqlite` (or whatever combination of drivers you're using), and `PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled`. There can be more than one php.ini file. My Ubuntu box has three. Try `find /etc -name php.ini`.

Comment: You are right. I have many php.ini. But I edited php.ini file, the file is displayed in phpinfo. I think this php.ini is right. And I can see PDO driver is sqlite only in phpinfo. Thanks for comment.